# Give background to <i> tag when input focus

Tags: html, css, forms, input, focus

There is an "icon" next to the input. I want that when I click on the input, give that icon a background (In the sample with the color I just want to test it).

I already tried some of the answers what I found here, but didn't work.

```
<div class="part">
   <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
   <input type="text" name="contactName">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.contact .part input:focus + i {
   color: red;
}
```

When I tried with label, without + symbol or something else, It didn't work either. I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the order of the `<input>` and the `<i>` element in the HTML. Style `.part` as a flexbox (or `inline-flex`), and then use `order: 1` on the `<input>` to visually position it after the `<i>`. Now the `input:focus + i` will work:

```css
.part {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.part input {
  order: 1;
}

.part input:focus + i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="part">
  <input type="text" name="contactName">
  <i class="fas fa-info-circle">X</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The sibling selector (`+`) only points in one direction, so that when you say `foo + bar`, you're selecting `bar` only when it directly follows `foo`.

Conceptually, the CSS works something like this:

> Within the elements of class `container`, look for any elements of class `part`, and inside that element, look for any input that has focus. If it's directly followed by an `i` element, color that red.

In your case, the CSS will only apply if `i` comes after the input.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! A good solution for you, unless you need to support IE and Edge, would be to use `:focus-within`, like this: `.part:focus-within i { color: red; }`. If you do need to support IE and Edge, you can still use this with a simple polyfill like this one: https://gist.github.com/aFarkas/a7e0d85450f323d5e164